# Android: Content provider access in a service

Tags: android, service, android-activity, android-contentprovider

I am creating an application that is supposed to start a service which should access to a content provider in android and send some data to an external server.

When accessing the content provider, I need to use the `managedQuery` function, which has to be called in an `Activity`. How should I address this issue?

I don't know whether to create another `Activity` class in order to write the `Content Provider` access method here.
How should I send the data to the server, from the `Service` itself?

Not sure if I explained myself clearly..

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need the `ContentResolver` class:

```
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
Cursor c = cr.query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder);

// do something

c.close();
```

Comment: mmmm right! I still didn't get the concept of `Content Provider` and `Content Resolver` clearly :) Thanks!